# Can't call instance method of derived inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
public class A extends Q implements T {
   public class B extends Z {
      public void D(int A, int B) {
      }
   }
   private Z z;
   public A() {
     // other stuff
     z = new B(/** params **/);
     // more stuff
   }
   void C () {
      ((B)z).D(2,3);
   }
}
```

The code is structured like that (can't give the full snippet due to legal reasons) When I try to call D, I get symbol not found error from java compiler. Z, Q, and T are defined in different files and they *do* compile without error.

Comment: You can't cast `Z` to `B`. Try to cast `z` instead.

Comment: What you want to achieve here. this is not correct as per the concept. multiple       
 mistake . No object initialized . Cant cast Z to B.  Z is super class  Z z=new B(); is possible but B b=new Z(); not. Does D(A,B) exist in Z. Please clarify your problem statement.

Comment: Well, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are always written in camelCase `A`, `B` and `D` should be `a`, `b` and `d` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if you have a class vehicle(Z) and a class truck(B) which is also a vehicle but can attachCargo(D). Then if we know we have any vehicle(z) and we just assume its a truck ( (B z) ), we cannot know for sure if it actually can attachCargo since we just assumed it were a truck(B). What you could do is create a constructor that takes in a vehicle(Z) and constructs a truck(B) from the information given. This new truck can be treated like a vehicle since it is one, but as we know it is a truck, we can also treat it like a truck:

```
class AClass extends Q implements T
{

    class B extends Z
    {
        boolean CargoAttached;

        public B()
        {

        }

        public B(Z z)
        {
            CargoAttached = false;
        }

        public void D(int A, int B)
        {
        }
    }

    private Z z = new Z();

    void C()
    {
        z = (new B(z));
        ((B) z).D(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly fine